# Java: String.contains matches exact word

Tags: java, string

In Java

```
String term = "search engines"
String subterm_1 = "engine"
String subterm_2 = "engines"
```

If I do `term.contains(subterm_1)` it returns `true`. I don't want that. I want the `subterm` to exactly match one of the words in `term`

Therefore something like `term.contains(subterm_1)` returns `false` and `term.contains(subterm_2)` returns `true`

Comment: Will the words always be separated by spaces?

Comment: Yes words are always separated by spaces

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> \b    Matches a word boundary where a word character is [a-zA-Z0-9_].

This should work for you, and you could easily reuse this method.

```
public class testMatcher {
public static void main(String[] args){

    String source1="search engines";
    String source2="search engine";
    String subterm_1 = "engines";
    String subterm_2 = "engine";

    System.out.println(isContain(source1,subterm_1));
    System.out.println(isContain(source2,subterm_1));
    System.out.println(isContain(source1,subterm_2));
    System.out.println(isContain(source2,subterm_2));

}

    private static boolean isContain(String source, String subItem){
         String pattern = "\\b"+subItem+"\\b";
         Pattern p=Pattern.compile(pattern);
         Matcher m=p.matcher(source);
         return m.find();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
true
```

Comment: This has a flaw when the subitem has a regex special character. For example `isContain("live","l.ve")` will return true. I have submitted an edit for correcting this.

Comment: @MendrikaSandratra where it is?

Comment: @bdevloper since i need validation for my edits, i think no one has validate it yet. My correction is using `"\\b" + Pattern.quote(subitem) + "\\b"` so the subItem is a regex literal

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using word boundaries.  If you compile a pattern like \bengines\b, your regular expression will only match on complete words.

Here is an explanation of word boundaries, as well as some examples.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Also, here is the java API for the pattern, which does include word boundaries
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Here is an example using your requirements above

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bengines\\b");
  Matcher m = p.matcher("search engines");
  System.out.println("matches: " + m.find());

  p = Pattern.compile("\\bengine\\b");
  m = p.matcher("search engines");
  System.out.println("matches: " + m.find());
```

and here is the output:

```
matches: true
matches: false
```

Answer (score 3):

If the words are always separated by spaces, this is one way to go:

```
String string = "search engines";
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if(parts[i].equals("engine")) {
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want the subterm to exactly match one of the words in term

Then you can't use `contains()`. You could split the term into words and check equality (with or without case sensitivity).

```
boolean hasTerm = false;
for (String word : term.split("\\s+") {
  if (word.equals("engine")) {
    hasTerm = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use indexOf instead and then check whether char at the poistion

```
index + length of string plus +1 == ` ` or EOS
```

or I am sure there is a regex way as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since the contains method verify if does exist that array of char in the string, it will aways return true, you will have to use Regex to make this validation.

If the words are aways separed by space it is easier, you can use the \s regex to get it.

Here is a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to split the string by spaces, convert it to a list, and then use the `contains` method to check for exact matches, like so:

```
String[] results = term.split("\\s+");
Boolean matchFound = Arrays.asList(results).contains(subterm_1);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VFU13839)